# Rover 5 Robot Platform Motor Controller

Tags: motor, controller

I am about to purchase a Rover 5 Robot Platform from Spark Fun and I would like to know what type of motor controller I should get, and is there a controlling device instead such as a remote control? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Big question (and probably one that you'd be better asking SparkFun about - they seem to have a very helpful and knowledgeable staff).

Lots of things to look at:

1. Stall current

   - Seems to be 2.5A ([manual](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/Rover%205%20Introduction.pdf))
   - There's a comment on the site stating that it seems to be a total stall current (4 motors at ~500mA each)
2. Comfort with electronics

   - Will you be comfortable hooking it to an Arduino/RaspPi?
   - Or are you keen for plug and play remote control with a standard out of the box transmitter/receiver?

Suggestions:

- [All bells and whistles](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1495) - feedback, lots of interface options, but rather expensive.
- [Simpler alternative](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/713) - if you are rather comfortable with electronics the [L298](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/L298_H_Bridge.pdf) is a very nice H bridge chip, rather easy to use.

(no affiliation to pololu - just like their gear)